# Unconventional Propeller Efficiency

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, aerodynamics

I am very inexperienced in propellers and fluid dynamics, but I have been experimenting with propellers. I messed around with propellers between 2 and 12 blades; theoretically, its obvious that the fewer the blades you use, the more efficient the prop. However, I found a general loss of efficiency from 2-4, and a sudden spike of efficiency at 5 blades (the most efficient in this system), then dropping until 12. I have been calculating efficiency simply with power out vs power in.

The system is a simple DC brushed motor driving a prop of diameter 0.2m and hub diameter of 0.05m. Blade angle is 30 degrees and are flat, i.e. zero camber.

Can anyone explain why this is so?

(I have also heard some speculation that more blades can increase efficiency as it distributes power more equally. Is there any truth to this?)

[image: sample data]

Comment: not enough info to figure out this problem. Data?

Comment: I would check your data reduction formulas and repeat each data point 5x, then chart the averages.

Comment: Each point is already an average of 5 collected points

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of the fluctuation in the measurements. How long did you measure input/output energy for? Was the motor/moving parts heated up to equilibrium when measuring each datapoint? It is just a hunch, but it is possible that the fluctuations you see are simply due to measurement setup.

That being said, I would guess that there is no straight answer as to why propellers show a certain efficiency. The fluid dynamics involved are by their very nature turbulent and therefore extremely hard to analyze.

"theoretically, its obvious that the fewer the blades you use, the more efficient the prop". Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Power was measured 5 times for three seconds at a time and averaged.  Something I had read about power distribution between blades.

Comment: That seems reasonable enough. Sorry I can't help you but I found this blog post which talks about some of the effects which are involved: 
http://aerotrash.over-blog.com/2015/02/2-blade-vs-3-blade-and-4-blade-propellers.html